# FaceBook Login com API REST

Tags: android, rest, facebook-sdk, oauth2

Integrei um app Android com o FaceBook e já consigo fazer o login por lá.

Agora, eu tenho que integrar esse o login do FaceBook com a parte de autenticação da minha API. Por exemplo, agora, o que consigo fazer é logar pelo FB e se estiver tudo certo, mando para outra activity. Mas, para começar a consumir recursos da API, eu preciso do token que é gerado por ela.

Alguéms sabe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Depois da resposta do login feito via Facebook.

Você pode conferir se a sessão está realmente aberta, e pegar o token do usuário

Exemplo:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session.isOpened()) {
    Log.d("token", session.getAccessToken());
}
```

Comment: Sim, mas esse login é válido para o FaceBook. Não para a minha API REST, ela teria que gerar um token pra mim, correto?